# How to get correlated features in a list with a specific format?

Tags: python, pandas, list, series

I am learning pandas. I need help with the following.
I am trying to find out the highest correlated features from the correlation matrix.

```
# Iris Dataset
features = ['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width','class']
data = pd.read_csv("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data",\
                           header = None,\
                           names = features)
correlation = data.corr()
c = correlation.where(np.triu(np.ones(correlation.shape),k=1).astype(np.bool)).stack().sort_values(ascending = False)
highest = c[c>0.5]
print(highest)
print(highest.index)
```

The output of the above snippet is:

```
petal_length  petal_width     0.962757
sepal_length  petal_length    0.871754
              petal_width     0.817954
dtype: float64
MultiIndex(levels=[['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width'], ['sepal_length', 'sepal_width', 'petal_length', 'petal_width']],
           labels=[[2, 0, 0], [3, 2, 3]])
```

Is there any possibility to convert the output of the series 'highest' into a list with the format specified below?

```
list = [['petal_length','petal_width',0.962757],['sepal_length','petal_length',0.871754]['sepal_length','petal_width',0.817954]]
```

In layman's terms, I need the index columns (both columns) in a list from the series.

I tried this and its working. but I need the list like above:

```
length = highest.shape[0]
list = []
for i in range(length):
    list.append(highest.index[i])
print('list =',list)
```

Output:

```
list = [('petal_length', 'petal_width'), ('sepal_length', 'petal_length'), ('sepal_length', 'petal_width')]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
highest.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['petal_length', 'petal_width', 0.9627570970509667],
 ['sepal_length', 'petal_length', 0.8717541573048719],
 ['sepal_length', 'petal_width', 0.8179536333691635]]
```

Comment: @JSabariVishnuJayanthan Would you consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this answer?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot.